# How to find the CP violating effective operator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, cp-violation, 1pi-effective-action

I've been meeting with one not-very-small problem in arriving at 
(3.3) in Shaposhnikov's "Structure of the high temperature gauge ground state and electroweak production of the barygon asymmetry" (1988).

My question is how we can get this contribution based on what is said in *section 3* of this paper. I've been trying hard on this pretty much in vain. Could you please show me how to arrive at this expression and explain more the points leading to the derivation of (3.3), *quantitatively*? I'm really stuck in finding how the perturbation is related to CP.

The highlighted lines below require further calculation elucidation.[image]

Comment: Few of us will have access to the paper. Can you edit your question to add the details from the paper?

Comment: Maybe you could citate the relevant parts.